# Not available to insert data?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to add data to this table, but I am not able to do that because of this "not available to insert data" error. Does anyone know why and how can I fix this? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the definition of the table in question?  Is the column in question a computed column for example?

Comment: Please post your code of your insert statement. You likely won't get any helpful answers by only providing a couple screenshots.

Comment: What "code", @tim? It is Apex and its SQL Workshop, Object Browser. There's no "code" there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about `PLATA` column's datatype - `FLOAT`. Change it to `NUMBER`.

```
alter table bk_zaposleni modify plata number;
```

Comment: I never got to thank you for helping me! 
You saved me in my finals project.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome :) I'm glad if it helped.